# PHP Strict Standards: Declaration of uploaded::Download() should be compatible with DownloadClass::Download

Tags: php, strict

I just open this topic because i'm trying to figure this out for days....

> Error_log [08-Aug-2013 14:57:37 UTC] PHP Strict Standards: Declaration of uploaded::Download() should be compatible with DownloadClass::Download($link, $FileName, $cookie = 0, $post = 0, $referer = '', $caching = false) in /home/srv26/public_html/hosts/uploaded.class.php on line 3

Line 3:

```
final class uploaded extends DownloadClass implements Hosts {
```

Does anyeone have any idea of this error? Thanks for all! =)

```
final class uploaded extends DownloadClass implements Hosts {
    public static function Download($link, $caching = false) {
        parent::Download($Frag, '', $Cookies, 0, '', $caching);
    }
}


abstract class DownloadClass extends cmmf {
    protected static function Download($link, $FileName, $cookie = 0, $post = 0, $referer = '', $caching = false){
        [..........]
    }
}
```

---

uploaded.class
The file is like this...

```
final class uploaded extends DownloadClass implements Hosts {
    public static function Download($link, $caching = false) {
        parent::Download($Frag, '', $Cookies, 0, '', $caching);
    }
}

DownloadClass

abstract class DownloadClass extends cmmf {
    protected static function Download($link, $FileName, $cookie = 0, $post = 0, $referer = '', $caching = false){
        [..........]
    }
}
```

Comment: The signatures of the methods should match.

Comment: what do you mean by that? Can you give me an example please?

Comment: The two `Downloads` methods accept different parameters.

Comment: when i call this class i use parent::Download($Frag, '', $Cookies, 0, '', $caching);

Comment: Could you give us the possible THREE definitions of the `function Downloads()` of your class `uploaded`, `DownloadClass` and `Hosts` (the interface might not have it). If you compare them, they should have the same set of parameters. If not: That triggers the error.

Comment: please check the new answer with more details ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy thing:

The two definitions of the Download function differ.

Make them the same.

The point of extending an abstract class is that the abstract class sets the template for ALL methods that any child class might have, so that it does not matter for any consuming code to check WHICH incarnation of child class it has to deal with.

So you wanted to have a shortcut parameter list that gets filled with defined default variables. That will work only if you create a new function name. If you are using the same function name, that error will stay.

Comment: Could you give me an example of that, please? Please check the other post here with part of the file..

Comment: The `DownloadClass::Download()` method has 6 parameters. The `uploaded::Download()` method has only 2. It MUST have 6 of the same type.

Comment: Man, thank you veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery much!!!!! I change the Download for DownloadFile and its ok now =))